# Regarding Web Services, REST, and its types

Tags: web-services, rest, soap

What different types of Web Services are there?
During my searching I have come across:
1) REST vs. SOAP
2) REST vs. Big Web Services
3) REST vs. Arbitrary Web Services
What are they? What’s the difference between them? And what are the main types of Web Services? Do REST/SOAP/Big Web Services/Arbitrary Web Services form a hierarchy of some sort? Are there classes, and sub-classes of Web Services?

Also I have read that a web service is made up of: WSDL + SOAP + UDDI. If so, then how come people differentiate between RESTful web service, and a SOAP Web Service, when every Web Service must use SOAP?

What exactly is REST? I understand that REST uses HTTP, and that a REST operation accesses data, rather than performing an operation. But is it just a theory/methadology, or is it a tool, or something else?

How does REST contribute to giving us Clean URLs?
I’ve spent close to a whole day searching upon these things, but I am still a bit unclear. Any info regarding these things will be MUCH appreciated.

Comment: Check the FAQ and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/671118/what-exactly-is-restful-programming/9103525#9103525

Comment: here is the info page http://stackoverflow.com/tags/rest/info